# Bounding linear transformation by a constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I am stuck on an exercise in Spivak which comes up alot in the text.

> **Exercise Spivak 1-10:** If $T:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation, show that there is a number $M$ such that
> $|T(h)|<M|h|$ for all $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Hint: estimate $|T(h)|$ in
> terms of $|h|$ and the entries in the matrix $T$.

My work is as follows

Assume that $\{\textbf{e}_1,\dots, \textbf{e}_m\}$ is a basis for $R^m$ and $\{\textbf{u}_1,\dots, \textbf{u}_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then Fix $h=c_1\textbf{e}_1+\dots+c_m\textbf{e}_m\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Finally, assume that $t_{ij}$ are the entries for the matrix representation of $T$.

$$|T(h)|\\
=\left|\sum_{i=1}^mc_iT(e_i)\right|\\
=\left|\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nc_it_{ij}\textbf{u}_j\right|\\
\leq\sum_{i=1}^m\left|\sum_{j=1}^nc_it_{ij}\textbf{u}_j \right|\\
=\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (c_i t_{ij})^2 }$$.

I have seen that I need to apply the Cauchy Schwarz inequality however I am not sure how to apply this due to the square inside of the square root in the last equality. How can I proceed from here? (I'm not worried about the step where I need to take the max over all of the matrix entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$|T(h)|\\
=\left|\sum_{i=1}^mc_iT(e_i)\right|\\
=\left|\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nc_it_{ij}\textbf{u}_j\right|\\
\leq\sum_{i=1}^m\left|\sum_{j=1}^nc_it_{ij}\textbf{u}_j \right|\\
\leq \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nc_i|t_{ij}||\textbf{u}_j |\\.$$
Now switch the order of summation and apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the sum over $i$.

Comment: Would this look like $\leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^mc_i^2 \right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|t_{ij}||\textbf{u}_j|\right)^2 \right)}$?

Comment: @SamKirkiles Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ah then we have $|h| \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|t_{ij}||\textbf{u}_j|\right)^2 }$? And from here we can set $M$ accorrdingly to the second factor? Would I still have to set $M$ to be defined using the max or could I just set $M=\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|t_{ij}||\textbf{u}_j|\right)^2 }$

Comment: @cmk Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

Matrices are fine, but I like to do this without them.

Let $S$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^m.$ Then $S$ is compact. Since $T$ is continuous, $T(S)$ is compact. Therefore $T$ is bounded on $S,$ i.e., there exists $M>0$ such that $|T(x)| \le M$ for each $x\in S.$

Let $v\in \mathbb R^m.$ If $v=0,$ then $T(v)=0.$ If $v\ne 0,$ let $u=v/|v|.$ Then $u\in S$ and $v=|v|u.$ Thus

$$|T(v)|=|T(|v|u)| = |v||T(u)|\le |v|M.$$

This gives the result.